# UIImagePickerController within a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a little iOS project/test i am performing where i am calling an UIImagePickerContoller with the source set to the iPhones camera.

I am wanting to load this "live" camera into a smaller UIView box in my interface. I am getting the camera to load and show up, but not in the UIView. Here's the code I am working with :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UIImagePickerController *scope = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    [scope setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [scope setShowsCameraControls:NO];
    [scope setEditing:NO];
    [scope setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    [cameraDisplayView addSubview:scope.view];
    [scope viewWillAppear:YES];

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, do you get the "ordinary" camera interface, or what is the problem?

Comment: I get the normal camera to show up, but it is not within my UIView that I created within interface builder. The closest thing to showing what i am trying to do is from the new Super 8 app... http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/super-8/id435739918?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `cameraOverlayView` property to draw other views on top of the camera view, not the other way around.

See the documentation for [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html). You cannot force the camera picker controller into a `UIView`, you have to draw on top of the camera picker controller.

(And then you could set one of you overlaying views to `clearColor` to get a window to the camera controller.)

Answer (score -1):

Set your imagepickercontroller frame size to your parent view like this:

```
scope.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, cameraDisplayView.frame.size.width, cameraDisplayView.frame.size.height);
```

and than add your imagepickercontroller into your view.

```
[cameraDisplayView addSubview:scope.view];
```

Comment: the scope `UIImagePickerController` is a modal and cannot be added as a subview

Comment: @AbuYusuph UIImagePickerController is a modal but not its view . I added the view of controller . please see.